# How did the adverbial use of "smack" come into use?

Tags: word-usage

How did the adverbial use of "smack" come into use? For example: "smack in the middle" or "smack in front" of something etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are several similar phrases, all related to one another: **smack dab, slap dab, smack bang, slap bang.** They may be hyphenated or not.

**Slap and smack**, and **bang and dab** combine indicate a noise and suddenness.

**OED**

> **smack-dab,** adv.
>
> Forms:  Also smack dab.
>
> Etymology: < smack v.  + dab adv.
>
> *U.S. dialect and colloquial.*
>
> **Exactly, precisely; with a smack.** Cf. slap-dab adv.
>
> 1892   Dial. Notes 1 232   *He hit him smack dab in the mouth.*

> **slap-dab**
>
> *North American dialect and colloquial.*
> **slap-dab   = slap-bang adv.**  *Cf. smack-dab adv.*
>
> 1886   Turf, Field & Farm XLII. 174/3   *He was goin' that fas' he run
> slap-dab agin me afo' he seed me.*

> **dab, adv.**
>
> **Etymology:** The verb-stem or noun used elliptically.
> **With a dab, or sudden contact.**
>
> 1600   R. Armin Foole vpon Foole sig. C2v   *Hee droopt downe..as
> heauy as if a leaden Plummet..had fallen on the earth dab.* [He
> dropped down…as heavily like a lead weight suddenly falling to the ground.]

> **slap, adv.**
>
> **Etymology:** < Low German slapp (German schlapp), of imitative origin.
>
> *colloquial.*
>
> **1. With, or as with, a slap or smart quick blow; quickly, suddenly,
> without warning or notice:**    a. In general use (frequently
> parenthetic); also with off, down.
>
> 1672   Duke of Buckingham Rehearsal iii. 21   *First one speaks, then
> presently t'others upon him slap, with a Repartee.*

> **Smack** (verb)
>
> **7. Used with adverbial force.**
>
> **a. With, or as with, a smack; suddenly and violently; slap.** Also
> with down, through, etc.
>
> 1782   W. Cowper Hist. John Gilpin in Public Advertiser 14 Nov.
> *Smack went the Whip, round went the Wheels.*
>
> 1799   King George IV in Paget Papers (1896) I. 150
> *He..tumbled..smack on his face.*

Answer (score 1):

According to Etymonline the adverbial usage of smack is quite old (late 18th c.) probably as a figurative extension of its original verbal usage.

smack(adv.)

> "suddenly, directly, aggressively, plump, straight," 1782, from smack (v.1); the extended form smack-dab is attested from 1892, American English colloquial (slap-dab is from 1886).